# How can I get page faults statistics from kernel

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, performancecounter, papi

How can I get page faults statistics from kernel for my application while it is running?
What about other events, like inter-cpu migrations count in SMP nodes, or number of context switches?

I want to count such events for various small parts of the program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be wanting to use the "perf" tools packaged with the kernel. See [here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find interesting stuff looking at PAPI, Likwid or even Oprofile.

Answer (score 4):

The [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) records some of that information, but (I believe) not all of it, and definitely not "for various small parts", but only for the process as a whole.  I doubt the kernel records e.g. context switches or page faults "for various small parts" anywhere.  Maybe you can take snapshots of the applicable `/proc` pseudofiles at the start and end of each "small part" and take the difference -- for some applications (that don't branch every which way all of the time) that might be an acceptable substitute.

Comment: which records from procfs can i use? is there statistics of cpu migrations and cntx switches?

Comment: Yes, I can do smth (like reading a file) between measured parts.

Comment: there is a counter for cntx switch: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/kernel/sched.c#L2962
`long long nr_context_switches()`